# Prove : $a^2+b^2+c^2≤ \frac{2}{3}\cdot (a^3+b^3+c^3)+1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, summation

Prove that by Cauchy inequality:
$a^2+b^2+c^2≤ \frac{2}{3}\cdot (a^3+b^3+c^3)+1$
$a,b,c$ are a positive numbers
$a*b*c=1$

Comment: When you ask a question you need to include context and the work you've done to try to solve it (or at least some ideas). Questions like “this is my problem, fix it” go unanswered

Comment: By AM-GM, $$2a^3 + 1 =a^3+a^3+1\ge 3 \sqrt[3]{a^6}=3a^2.$$ The conclusion now follows by applying the same argumentation also for $b$ and $c$ and summing. The condition $abc=1$ seems superfluous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq \frac{2}{3}(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 1
\end{equation}

Proof:

Express $\frac{2}{3}(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)$ as:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{2}{3}(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) = \frac{2}{3}a^3 + \frac{2}{3}b^3 + \frac{2}{3}c^3
\end{equation}

Reorganize the original inequality:

\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq \frac{2}{3}a^3 + \frac{2}{3}b^3 + \frac{2}{3}c^3 + 1
\end{equation}

Subtract $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ from both sides:

\begin{equation}
    0 \leq \frac{2}{3}a^3 + \frac{2}{3}b^3 + \frac{2}{3}c^3 + 1 - a^2 - b^2 - c^2
\end{equation}

Factorize the right-hand side expression:

\begin{equation}
    0 \leq \frac{1}{3}(2a^3 - 3a^2 + 1) + \frac{1}{3}(2b^3 - 3b^2 + 1) + \frac{1}{3}(2c^3 - 3c^2 + 1)
\end{equation}

Decompose cubes and factorize:

\begin{equation}
    0 \leq \frac{1}{3}(a - 1)^2(2a + 1) + \frac{1}{3}(b - 1)^2(2b + 1) + \frac{1}{3}(c - 1)^2(2c + 1)
\end{equation}

Since $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$, $(a - 1)^2$, $(b - 1)^2$, $(c - 1)^2$ are non-negative, the expression is always non-negative.

Therefore, the original inequality holds.

Comment: [Enforcement of quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the inequality as: $$a^2 + b^2+c^2 \leq \frac{2}{3}(a^3+b^3+c^3)+abc \quad (*)$$

These inequalities are due to AM-GM: $$a^{7/3}b^{1/3}c^{1/3} \leq \frac{a^3+a^3+abc}{3},$$

$$a^{1/3}b^{7/3}c^{1/3} \leq \frac{b^3+b^3+abc}{3},$$

$$a^{1/3}b^{1/3}c^{7/3} \leq \frac{c^3+c^3+abc}{3}.$$

If we add these three inequalities we get $(*)$, since $a^{7/3}b^{1/3}c^{1/3}=a^2,$ $ a^{1/3}b^{7/3}c^{1/3}=b^2,$ $a^{1/3}b^{1/3}c^{7/3}=c^2.$

Comment: Fantastic solution!

Comment: [Enforcement of quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)